# WCF not loading from IIS

Tags: c#, database, web-services, wcf, iis

I have made a WCF service that runs perfectly fine from Visual Studio. The published version however, refuses to do anything. I'm using the same port and same IP..  I right click "Sites", click "Add Website", give it a name, use DefaultAppPool, choose the file the WCF is nested in, type:http, set it to my IP, and use the Port that worked in Visual studio.. 52811. I give it no host name, and click OK.  Then, once I click "Browse xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:52811 (http)" under Browse Website, it just loads. Forever .-. What could I be doing wrong?

my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>


    <!--<behavior>
      To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to 
    false before deployment 
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the 
    value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing 
    exception information
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior> -->
    <bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="restLargeBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
     maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
    transferMode="Streamed">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
      <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myWebEndPointBehavior">
          <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" 
    defaultBodyStyle="Bare" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" 
    helpEnabled="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>

      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
      <service name="WcfService2.Service1" 
    behaviorConfiguration="myServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" contract="WcfService2.IService1" 
    binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="restLargeBinding" 
    behaviorConfiguration="myWebEndPointBehavior"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" contract="WcfService2.IService1" 
    binding="mexHttpBinding"/> 
      </service>
    </services>

    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
     multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
      </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
       <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
       <!--
          To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value 
below 
    to true.
           Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder 
    information.
      -->
       <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
       </system.webServer>

     </configuration>
```

my ISerivice1.cs:

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Runtime.Serialization;
        using System.ServiceModel;
        using System.ServiceModel.Web;
        using System.Text;

    namespace WcfService2
    {
         // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to 
    change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file 
    together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {


        //Get Method//
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "getConNum")]
        List<CONTROLNUMBER> GetConNum();

        //Post Method//
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "AddConNum", BodyStyle = 
     WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = 
    WebMessageFormat.Json, 
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string AddConNum(string conNum);
        }
        [DataContract]
         public class CONTROLNUMBER
        {
            string conNum;

            [DataMember]
            public string ConNum
            {
                get { return conNum; }
                set { conNum = value; }
            }
            }

        }
```

Service1.svc.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WcfService2
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to 
    change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, 
    please select Service1.svc or Service1.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer 
 and 
    start debugging.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {

        //Connection String//
        private string conStr = "Data Source=xxxxxxx\\xxxxxxx;Initial 
    Catalog=xxxxxxxx;User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx";

    public string AddConNum(string conNum)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public List<CONTROLNUMBER> GetConNum()
    {
        List<CONTROLNUMBER> conNumList = new List<CONTROLNUMBER>();
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.conStr);
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM table1 
      WHERE CREATEDBY = 'Web' ", connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (sdr.Read())
        {

            CONTROLNUMBER conNum = new CONTROLNUMBER();
            conNum.ConNum = sdr["CONTROLNUMBER"].ToString();
            conNumList.Add(conNum);
        }
        return conNumList.ToList();
        }



    }



     }
```

Screenshots shown below:

[Chrome tab when run from Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUbIF.png)

[Hanging when run from IIS after publishing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3APWW.png)

I hope I have provided enough details, let me know if more is required. I have done some censoring of sensitive information with `x` , but the IP I am using from IIS is my computer's local IP, since in Visual Studio it was working with `localhost`. When I invoke in Visual Studio, it successfully runs my SQL command and I get information back from the database..

Comment: post more details or error page what you getting !!

Comment: I have updated the post to contain more details and screenshots